# Handling production/dev/testing configs in sails.js

Tags: sails.js

Does anyone know the best way to handle prod/dev/test config switching in sails? I really like how actionhero.js automatically loads config/environment/{env}.js based on the contents of NODE_ENV but I don't see a built-in way to do something similar in sails. I noticed that sails will load any file in config/ during server bootstrap so my hacky solution for now is to setup the following:

```
config/
|-- local.js
|-- environment/
|---- production.js
|---- staging.js
|---- development.js
|---- testing.js
```

Then in each {env}.js file, I just extend config like this:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Enter any environment specific config changes
  config.db = {
    db_host: foo,
    db_port: bar
  }
  config.otherThing = {
    somevar: 'someval'
  }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since Sails 0.10-rc6 this got improved and you can now add an `env` subfolder in `config` to change settings for different environments.

So you could simply add a file `/config/env/development.js` or `/config/env/production.js` that can override all the necessary settings

See https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/pull/1638 for more details.

Example to change the port and database adapter, e.g. for `production` environment in your `production.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  port: 80
};

module.exports.models = {

  // Your app's default connection.
  // i.e. the name of one of your app's connections (see `config/connections.js`)
  //
  // (defaults to localDiskDb)
  connection: 'someMongodbServer'
};
```

Comment: It would be awesome if there was an example of how to use this feature. For example, does one simply need to set a session.url variable in config/env/production.js to the URL for the mongo database? (or do you need to use module.exports.session({url: ...})

Comment: This answer does not explain how the above plays with local.js, and NODE_ENV.

Comment: Looks like Sails loads in `config/env/<NODE_ENV>.js`.

Comment: @SteveKehlet Just want to confirm that this is the case for Sails v0.11

Answer (score 12):

Simply go to config/env/production.js & set port and environment manually

And use NODE_ENV

For Windows use
`set NODE_ENV=production`

For MAC/Linux use `export NODE_ENV=production`

OR

<kbd>sails lift --prod</kbd>

[image]

Comment: This answer seems to be correct - why was it down voted?

Answer (score 6):

I did this by making `config/local.js` require additional config files depending on `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

**In `config/local.js`**

```
var fs = require('fs'),
   lodash = require('lodash');

// config.local.js
module.exports = (function () {
  var defaults = {
    env: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
    port: process.env.PORT || 1337,
    config: {
      paths: {
        environments: __dirname + '/environments'
      }
    }
  };

  var envConfigPath = defaults.config.paths.environments + '/' + defaults.env + '.js';
  var environment = {};

  if (fs.existsSync(envConfigPath)) {
    var environment = require(envConfigPath);
    logger.info('Loaded environment config for ' + defaults.env + '.');
  } else {
    logger.warn('Environment config for ' + defaults.env +' not found.');
  }
  return _.merge(defaults, environment);
}());
```

**In `.gitignore`:**

```
# config.local.js
config/environments
```

**This gives you:**

- Overrides for any config based on your `env` by defining them in `config/environments/{env}.js`
- `sails.config{env}` holding all your environment specific configuration, just as your solution does
- Nice declarative `{env}` files
- Warnings about missing `{env}` files

Comment: Nice approach, thanks for sharing! For anyone implementing, there there are a few dependencies here that may not be apparent on first look (namely `logger` and `lodash`, but you'd have to require `fs` as well).

Comment: Hey, updated the answer to reflect the dependencies. `logger` should be injected into global scope by sails (in v0.10, that is).

Comment: Oh, good call!  One other thing that may not be obvious—I had to modify `require(envConfigPath)` to `var environment = require(envConfigPath)`, though this assumes you are setting up the env files like this: `module.exports = {
  env: 'production',
  port: 80
};
`

Comment: Ouch. You are totally right there - your fix is what I actually have in my source. Must have deleted it accidentally when formatting for SO. Should stop to answer questions after 2 a.m. Anyway - glad you like the approach.

Comment: I had to slightly modify this code to get it to work with the latest sails 0.10-rc9. Adding/changing `_ = require('lodash'); CaptainsLog = require('captains-log');` at the beginning of the snippet and then right after `module.exports` I added `var log = CaptainsLog();`. Seems to be working perfectly now.