# node js development production configurations

Tags: node.js, sails.js

How do we create different development and production configuration in node js/sails?

Also, what is the best way to manage migration between test and production, post production?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling production/dev/testing configs in sails.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790465/handling-production-dev-testing-configs-in-sails-js)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `config/env` files to overwrite your configuration appropriately. Example production file:

```
module.exports = {

  /***************************************************************************
   * Set the default database connection for models in the production        *
   * environment (see config/connections.js and config/models.js )           *
   ***************************************************************************/

   models: {
     connection: 'someMysqlServer'
  },

  /***************************************************************************
   * Set the port in the production environment to 80                        *
   ***************************************************************************/

  port: 80,

  /***************************************************************************
   * Set the log level in production environment to "silent"                 *
   ***************************************************************************/

  log: {
    level: "silent"
  }

};
```

You can also define a `test.js` file there.

Why do you have migrate from a testing environment to a production one? This sounds wrong to me.